# Stablecoin Fixed price how to keep

Tags: stablecoins

I'm developing a stable coin. I need to update daily the amount of USDC that one mytoken will value

As an example

Today mytoken = 30 USDC
Tomorrow mytoken = 28 USDC
After tomorrow  my token = 31 USDC

The amount of USDC is calculated off chain at every day.

So in summary I need to update daily the fix daily price.

I'm thinking to use burn and mint model.

How should I resolve this requirement ?

Thanks

Comment: The easiest way is to run a program daily is using you OS scheduler. Usually linux, windows, mac have such functionality.

Comment: Ismael, can you give me more explanation ? Are you mentioning crontab for doing what ?